# Forcing ssh connection to use rsa key authentication (no root)

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, openssh

Is there anyway as a standard user to be able to force all login attempts to my account to use rsaauthentication? I have a school linux login but obviously I don't have root access or sudo access, is there any way I can force ssh connections/logins to my account?

Comment: Just for the record, `RSAAuthentication` is for the old SSHv1 protocol, which is insecure and best forgotten. The current SSHv2 option is `PubkeyAuthentication`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't – all you can do is set a very strong password and never use it.

Comment: so best to actually have this set to off?